# How to fix Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value in valgrind?

Tags: c, valgrind

I have this piece of software that connects to a server then reads the data in chunks of `MAXIMUM` then copies the read data into a heap buffer, every thing works fine with out any errors or seg fault but when used with valgrind it detects an uninitialized variable that is used with strcpy

```
void func()
{
    // connects to server then enters this loop to receive data 
    while(1)
    {
        ret = recv(sd, resp, MAXIMUM);
        if (ret <= 0)break;
        else
        {
            /* copies data into a the heap buffer and reallocates the buffer to a bigger one for the next read */
        }
    }
    strcpy(str, ptr);
}
int main ()
{
    char string[MAXIMUM*100] = {0};
    fun(string);
}
```

valgrind output

```
==84026== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==84026== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==84026==    at 0x483F0B7: strcpy (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==84026==    by 0x10AA7B: tmp (delme.c:191)
==84026==    by 0x10AB4A: main (delme.c:210)
==84026== 
==84026== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

how do you properly initialize an array pointer to be used with `strcpy`

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us, and then show us the Valgrind output from that program.

Comment: there are many examples out there for how to create a heap buffer and read data from the server into that buffer, my question is about the `strcpy` and why does valgrind create an error

Comment: Pointers and heap allocations and reallocations could cause all kinds of weird behavior if you don't do it correctly. The problem isn't the `strcpy` call in itself, it's just a small part of a larger context. It's the larger context, which we know nothing about, that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be using `memcpy` instead of `strcpy` you only need to know the length of the data received from the server which is pretty easy to do

```
size_t total= 0;
while (1) 
{
    ret = recv(sd, resp, MAXIMUM);
    if (ret <= 0) break;
    total + =ret;
}
memcpy(str,ptr , total);
```

Comment: And if it's supposed to be a null-terminated string, then add it at the end. And very likely the `memcpy` call should be inside the loop, to append to the `std` buffer.

Comment: or you could simply do `str[total+1] = '\0'` right?

Comment: Almost, don't add `1` to `total`. :)